# Updating a map with another map in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I'd like to write the following function in Dafny, which updates a map `m1` with all mappings from `m2`, such that `m2` overrides `m1`:

```
function update_map<K, V>(m1: map<K, V>, m2: map<K, V>): map<K, V>
ensures
  (forall k :: k in m2 ==> update_map(m1, m2)[k] == m2[k]) &&
  (forall k :: !(k in m2) && k in m1 ==> update_map(m1, m2)[k] == m1[k]) &&
  (forall k :: !(k in m2) && !(k in m1) ==> !(k in update_map(m1, m2)))
{
  map k | (k in m1 || k in m2) :: if k in m2 then m2[k] else m1[k]
}
```

I got the following errors:

```
Dafny 2.2.0.10923
stdin.dfy(7,2): Error: a map comprehension involved in a function definition is not allowed to depend on the set of allocated references; Dafny's heuristics can't figure out a bound for the values of 'k' (perhaps declare its type, 'K', as 'K(!new)')
stdin.dfy(7,2): Error: a map comprehension must produce a finite set, but Dafny's heuristics can't figure out how to produce a bounded set of values for 'k'
2 resolution/type errors detected in stdin.dfy
```

I don't understand the first error, and for the second, if `m1` and `m2` both have finite domains, then their union is certainly finite as well, but how can I explain that to Dafny?

**UPDATE:**

After applying James' fixes, it works:

```
function update_map<K(!new), V>(m1: map<K, V>, m2: map<K, V>): map<K, V>
ensures
  (forall k :: k in m1 || k in m2 ==> k in update_map(m1, m2)) &&
  (forall k :: k in m2 ==> update_map(m1, m2)[k] == m2[k]) &&
  (forall k :: !(k in m2) && k in m1 ==> update_map(m1, m2)[k] == m1[k]) &&
  (forall k :: !(k in m2) && !(k in m1) ==> !(k in update_map(m1, m2)))
{
  map k | k in (m1.Keys + m2.Keys) :: if k in m2 then m2[k] else m1[k]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good questions! You are running across some known sharp edges in Dafny that are under-documented.

In the first error, Dafny is basically saying that the type variable `K` needs to be constrained to not be a reference type. You can do that by changing the function signature to start with

```
function update_map<K(!new), V>...
```

Here, `(!new)` is Dafny syntax meaning exactly that `K` may only be instantiated with value types, not reference types. (Unfortunately, `!new` is not yet documented, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/issues/181) about this.)

In the second error, you are running afoul of Dafny's limited syntactic heuristics to prove finiteness, as described in this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269470/surprising-dafny-failure-to-verify-boundedness-of-set-comprehension). The fix is to use Dafny's built-in set union operator instead of boolean disjunction, like this:

```
map k | k in m1.Keys + m2.Keys :: ...
```

(Here, I use `.Keys` to convert each map to the set of keys in its domain so that I can apply `+`, which works on sets but not maps.)

With those two type-checking-time errors fixed, you now get two new verification-time errors. Yay!

```
stdin.dfy(3,45): Error: element may not be in domain
stdin.dfy(4,59): Error: element may not be in domain
```

These are telling you that the statement of the postcondition itself is ill-formed, because you are indexing into maps using keys without properly hypothesizing that those keys are in the domain of the map. You can fix this by adding another postcondition (*before* the others), like this:

```
  (forall k :: k in m1 || k in m2 ==> k in update_map(m1, m2)) && ...
```

After that, the whole function verifies.

Comment: Thanks, now it all makes sense! I did actually try to use `K(!new)`, but I put it in `forall k : K(!new) :: ...`, which did not work.

Comment: A follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618673/how-to-read-dafny-counterexamples